# How to Increase Accuracy of CNN on Image Recognition

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN for image classification. Specifically, I am trying to create a lip reader that is able to classify an image of a segmented mouth with its associated phoneme. The images have a dimension of 64x64 and are flattened into a 1D array of length 4096. I have inserted the code for my current model below with its performance graphs and metrics. Does anyone have any advice for how I can continue to modify this model in order to raise the accuracy?

```
df = pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/labeled-frames-resized/labeled_frames.csv", error_bad_lines=False)
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
df['Phoneme'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df['Phoneme'])
labels = np.asarray(df[['Phoneme']].copy())
df = df.drop(df.columns[0], axis = 1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, labels, random_state = 42, test_size = 0.2, stratify = labels)
X_train = tf.reshape(X_train, (8113, 4096, 1))
X_test = tf.reshape(X_test, (2029, 4096, 1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters= 128, kernel_size=3, activation ='relu',strides = 2, padding = 'valid', input_shape= (4096, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Conv1D(filters= 128, kernel_size=3, activation ='relu',strides = 2, padding = 'valid'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Conv1D(filters= 128, kernel_size=3, activation ='relu',strides = 2, padding = 'valid'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Conv1D(filters= 128, kernel_size=3, activation ='relu',strides = 2, padding = 'valid'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(39)) 
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.4)

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs = 500, batch_size = 2048, validation_data = (X_test, y_test), shuffle = True)
```

[image: Model Graphs]

[image: Model Metrics]

Comment: What have you tried so far to optimize the model?  Can you provide some more information about your training data? How many images are there in the dataset? How did you set the spilt between train and test data? If it is a freely available dataset, it would help a lot if you share the source of it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm pretty new to deep learning, so I haven't done too much hyperparameter optimization except for the batch size (higher batch size yielded higher accuracy). Here is the link to my dataset: www.kaggle.com/richardcao1/labeled-frames-resized. There are a total of 39 unique phonemes, and each image (64x64 flattened to 4096) in the dataset corresponds to a phoneme. I split the dataset (10142 images) into 80% for training and 20% for testing. I'm open to any suggestions on the parameters I should experiment with for the model or any changes I should make to the dataset.

Comment: Why are you using 1D convolution instead of 2D? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: I've only worked with Conv1d so far because it seemed easier. Do you think using Conv2d will make a big difference?

Comment: Could you please update the code in your question and provide your complete code? I need to see how `X_train` and `y_train` are pre-processed before they are passed to the model.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated the code in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily convert it into 2D Convolution:

```
model.add(Conv2D(filters= 128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation ='relu',strides = (2,2), 
                 padding = 'valid', input_shape= (64,64,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))
...
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(39)) 
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

> I've only worked with Conv1d so far because it seemed easier.

**Can 1D Convolution be used on images?**

- Yes you can, but not recommended, unless you have a very specific case and know what you are doing. Assume your images as 1024x1024, what happens when you **flatten** them? The information that you extract with 2D Convolutions is more than 1D Convolutions.

**Explanation:**

You can use 1D convolution on images indeed, but not in every situation. (I might be wrong) When you flatten them, then every pixel will be a feature. If we wanted every pixel to be a feature, then we could use normal `Dense` layers after flattening also. But there would be a lot parameters to train. What I mean by this *(total parameters size not included)*:

```
model= tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(...)
...
])
```

When you flatten them you **might break the spatial coherence** of the images. Using 2D convolutions might gain you accuracy. What we do with 2D convolutions is we visit the image and see what we can extract as an **important feature**, with max or average pooling.

[image]

[image]

- You will not be able catch that much information with 1D convolutions.

[image]

- We can feed the pooled feature maps into Fully Connected Layers before making predictions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try conv2D instead.

Comment: In SO, the best way to say thanks is to accept the answer, if it solves your problem.